# how to find nth position tagName in javascript

Tags: javascript

find out nth position tagName, don't use id and classname. is it possible get nth number of tagname value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>

<script>

document.onclick = runfun;

function runfun(e)
{
    alert(e.target.tagName[]); // find out nth position tagName
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I think he wants to know the position in the list of DIVs of the one that he clicked on.

Comment: I see, makes more sense

Comment: it is the list of DIVs number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
function runfun(e) {
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
        if (e.target == allDivs[i]) {
            alert(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jvf0gs6n/)

Answer (score 0):

The event handler that you have in your code has a specific event target and that is the element that was clicked. It is a single DOM object and you can get its tag name. If you want to loop through all child elements of the body on the n-th iteration you will get the n-th element and you can access its tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all the tags and find match:

```
function check(e) {
    var tagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase(),
        allTags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    ([].slice.call(allTags)).forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (el === e.target) {
            alert(i);   
        }    
    });
}

document.addEventListener('click', check);
```

JSFiddle demo:

**http://jsfiddle.net/fmg44rvs/3/**

Comment: If you are already converting the node list to an array, I think using `.indexOf` is a more elegant solution.